# Hibernate elasticsearch transliteration(ICU transform)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate-search and hibernate-search-elasticsearch version 5.10.3.Final. I want to apply ICU transformation on some of the fields. Here is the filter in the elasticsearch documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.6/analysis-icu-transform.html

But I can't find а TokenFilterFactory in the lucene version that the hibernate-search dependencies uses. And in the TokenFilterDef the factory property is required. Does someone know how to achieve the transliteration with the hibernate-search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations and rely on `org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.analyzer.ElasticsearchTokenFilterFactory` to create a JSON token filter definition:

```
@AnalyzerDef(
    name = "myAnalyzer",
    tokenizer = ...,
    filter = @TokenFilterDef(
        name = "myLatinTransform",
        factory = ElasticsearchTokenFilterFactory.class,
        params = {
            @Parameter(name = "type", value = "'icu_transform'"),
            @Parameter(name = "id", value = "'Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC'")
        }
    )
)
```

Be careful: parameter values are interpreted as JSON, so string values must be quoted. Single quotes are allowed for convenience, though.

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_analyzers_using_the_code_analyzerdef_code_annotation

Or you can define the analyzer programmatically and benefit from a more natural API:

```
# In hibernate.properties
hibernate.search.elasticsearch.analysis_definition_provider com.acme.CustomAnalyzerProvider

public class CustomAnalyzerProvider implements ElasticsearchAnalysisDefinitionProvider {
    @Override
    public void register(ElasticsearchAnalysisDefinitionRegistryBuilder builder) {
        builder.analyzer( "myAnalyzer" )
                .withTokenizer( "whitespace" )
                .withTokenFilter( "myLatinTransform" );

        builder.tokenFilter( "myLatinTransform" )
                .type( "icu_transform" )
                .param( "id", "Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC" );
    }
}
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_analyzers_using_a_definition_provider